# Feeling of losing one's love

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose I break up with my girlfriend and I still love her very much. And it is impossible for us to resume our relationship. What's the best word or expression that will describe my feeling?

I feel great pain? I feel terribly miserable?

Comment: You have a few answers, but we are really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of research effort into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google Dictionary:
**love·lorn** /ˈləvˌlôrn/ Adjective: Unhappy because of unrequited love.

From *love* + *lorn* (obsolete) lost, doomed (archaic) abandoned, lonely, forlorn

Comment: To be precise, my girlfriend does not necessarily love me that much any more.

Comment: Yes. Lovelorn describes your unhappiness because your girlfriend's love is no longer available to you. It's a feeling of unhappiness caused by that loss or abandonment.

Answer (score 7):

You have a [broken heart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_heart).

Comment: ....And this is often used as the adjective "brokenhearted."

Comment: or the noun 'heartbreak'

Answer (score 5):

OP might be feeling [bereft](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bereft) - *(of a person) Lonely and abandoned*.